# Apache Camel Global SSL Configuration with Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am struggling to get the global SSL configuration to work. I am running
Apache Camel within Spring boot. It seems the configuration in
application.yml is ignored. The SSL context is not created and the
use-global-ssl-context-parameter is ignored for http component.

Versions

- Spring-Boot: 2.1.9-RELEASE
- Apache Camel: 2.24.2

Dependencies included in pom:

- camel-spring-boot
- camel-spring-boot-starter
- camel-http-starter

Configs (application.yml)

`camel:
  # To enable global SSL in undertow
  component:
    http:
      use-global-ssl-context-parameters: true
  ssl:
    config:
      key-managers:
        key-password: "changeit"
        key-store:
          resource: "/keystore.p12"
          password: "changeit"
          type: "PKCS12"
      trust-managers:
        key-store:
          resource: "/cacerts"
          password: "changeit"
          type: "jks"`

This is in a clean project created specifically to test the global SSL
context creation.

It seems I am missing a step somewhere?

Assistance appreciated.

Comment: is the below solution is working for you???, do you have an idea how to use the .jks file, can you please give this project Git link, I also facing the same issue,

Answer (score 0):

Replacing camel-http component camel-http4 resolved the issue. My understanding is that camel-http is deprecated.